# Depth management in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a number of playing card sprites. They are in a list, a parent card on top, followed by a child, that child is the parent of another child.

When I click on the 4th one down in the pile for example I want it and all of its children to be on top. How can I do this?

```
currentCard.parent.setChildIndex(currentCard, numChildren-1);
```

currentCard is the card the user clicks.

The above comes out with an error, the supplied index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
currentCard.parent.setChildIndex(currentCard, currentCard.parent.numChildren-1);
```

`numChildren` will refer to `this` otherwise. I'm not sure what `this` would be here since you only have that line of code, but if it's not `currentCard.parent` then `numChildren` could very easily be a larger number of children than how many `currentCard.parent` has, resulting in the out of bounds error. E.g. if `this` had 17 children and `currentCard.parent` has 5, then that line of code means you will be trying to access index 16 which is obviously out of bounds.